# Make background service always run and never killself or system destroy it

Tags: java, android, performance, android-service, background-process

Hello I am running a background service to check in my server if there is a new data.

But if I kill the App, the background service also dies.
If I run the background service on it;s on process, the system kill it after it has run a couple times.

**Manifest**

```
<service
            android:name=".backgroundSerive"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Option 2

```
<service
            android:name=".backgroundSerive"
android:process=":my_process"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

**MainAActivity - Starting the service**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, backgroundSerive.class );
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(i);
```

**Service**

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
...start runnable
        return  START_STICKY; 
    }
```

> > I try both option, The service keeps getting killed.

Any advice. To make my server always run.
thank you

Comment: Users can get rid of your service whenever users want to, through the Settings app. That is because the device is the user's device, not your device. [Only have your service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `startForeground()` from within  the service, to lower the chance of Android actually killing it. Please check out this [sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer) for an example implementation.

Answer (score 1):

startForeground function sends the service to foreground, so android system considers this operation as a foreground task. Which is very less likely to be killed.

If you have choosen the services destroy action as START_STICKY it would get destroyed but right after it destroyed it should be reinitialized with a null intent.

You may consider using Alarm for such event.
Since alarms are running in an internal process they reduce the app overhead, yet they provide recurring checks.